# Node.js server issue - added "/" when looking for files in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to write my first Nodejs server for getting to know Angular/Node and eventually the whole MEAN stack.

My server is running but there's a problem in my code, for some reason when I enter a non existing file, it should redirect to 404, but it doesn't. For some reason the URL gets a double dash;

How would I go about making the redirect to 404 work?

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9HbK.png)

Here is my code for the server so far.

```js
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    root = __dirname + '/public/', //magic var
    mime = require('mime');


  //Server
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  // Check is root is queried
  var fileName = '';
  var url = req.url;
  if (url === '/'){
    url = 'index.html'; // redirect when no file specified
  }
  fileName = root + url;



  // check if file exists
  fs.exists(fileName, function(exists){
    if (exists) {
      serveFile(fileName); // yes
    } else {
      path = root + '404.html'; //no
      serveFile(fileName);
    }
  })
  //serve file
  function serveFile(requestFile) {
    // maak a stream based on events
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(requestFile);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mime.lookup(requestFile)});
    stream.on('data', function (chunk){
      res.write(chunk);
    });
    stream.on('end', function(){
      res.end();
    });
    stream.on('error', function(err){
      console.log('error: '+ err);
    });
  }
});


server.listen(3000); //server start
console.log('Server gestart op http://localhost:3000 ');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>angular</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="styles/app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body ng-app class="bg">
    <h1>First name?</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type your name" ng-model='firstName'
              class="input-lg"/>
              <p>
                Hi, {{firstName}}
              </p>

              <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7720/night-animal-dog-pet.jpg" height="100px" width="100px"/>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Could anyone tell me what's going wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the `'/'` after public:

```
 root = __dirname + '/public'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer!
I did check that option, but in this case my redirect won't work. I mean: if I enter localhost:3000 the server won't respond as there's a / missing between public/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behaviour of Node JS. ie. If you request for xxx.com/sample.txt, then the req.url will be "/sample.txt".

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url

So you have consider that in your code, as @Jordan mentioned, remove the "/".

Your redirect also should work fine.

Comment: It indeed seems to work fine! Thanks for clearing this out, I fixed the redirect by adding "/" to 

`path = root + "/404.html"`


cheers!